# Place C++ class and its derivatives in specific section

Tags: c++, linker, g++, ld, linker-scripts

I have a section setup in my linker script, and I want to place all code for a particular C++ class as well as all other classes that derive from it in that section. Is this possible?

I've tried this but got a warning:

```
class Test __attribute__ ((section ("ss"), aligned(0x40)));

class Test {
public:
    void Foo(int a) {
        printf("Hello\n");
    }        
};
```

Warning:

```
test.cpp:19:7: warning: attribute ignored in declaration of ‘class Test’ [-Wattributes]
 class Test __attribute__ ((section ("ss"), aligned(0x40)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply the section attribute to each individual method in the class unfortunately, e.g.:

```
class Test {
public:
    __attribute__ ((section ("ss"), aligned(0x40))) void Foo(int a) {
        printf("Hello\n");
    }        
};
```

Comment: Does exposing these through shared libraries provide a way to do this? i.e place a subset of symbols in the shared library in a particular section.

Comment: I don't think putting your code in a shared library makes any difference, no.  (Sorry, just seen this).